# How can I iterate through options provided to a shell script through a command line?

Tags: shell, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a script that can be provided with [the potential] to have an unknown quantity of known arguments

That is, I know ALL the arguments that can be provided, but as they are all optional, they may not be getting provided all the time.

I have written this code (below), how can I send all the arguments provided to the 'setOptions' function? once they.are there I can iterate through them and process whats needed, but I don't have a clue how to pass them to the function.

Basically the case just checks to see if B or anything else is provided, if `B` then thats fine, but anything else needs to be iterated through and tested.

at the moment Im able to test if the value is a B or not and from there... well you can see.

```
  # request statement
  echo  "Enter 'B' to build or the name of test you wish to run."
  read testOptions
  # check the options
  case $testOptions in
    B )
      # tell them the tests are being rebuilt
      echo " The test will be rebuilt"
      COMMAND_LINE=$COMMAND_LINE" build"
      # display the command to be used and execute it.
      echo $COMMAND_LINE
      $COMMAND_LINE
    ;;
    * )
      # we are not rebuilding, take all the options and send to processing
      setOptions $testOptions #<- processes and builds the commandline from the  arguments
      # Execute the command
      executeOptions $testOptions #<- executes the command line
    ;;
  esac
```

Comment: Are you just looking for `read -a testOptions`?

Comment: I am honestly not sure, I know very little when it comes to shell script, if this was php, C# or JS I would be over and done with, but this is a bit different,  and quite enjoyable tbh!

Comment: The penny may have dropped for me just then, so if I were to use 

`sendOptions $testOptions`

Then in the function sendOptions, I would use `read -a $1` and basically a `case var in $1 .... iteration code... easc`

Comment: You don't usually use `$` in `read`: it takes zero or more variable _names_.